# crontab, результат запроса в curl

Tags: linux, curl, командная-строка

Я не силен в командной строке, но как говорится: "Сделать надо".
Мне нужно с помощью crontab выполнять команду:

```
curl http://mydite.com/usb.php?id=some
```

где some - результат выполнения команды

```
lsusb|grep ZTE|wc -l
```

Подскажите каким образом можно передать это значение?

Comment: Как выглядит результат выполнения команды?

Comment: int. В данный момент - 3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Примерно так:

`OUTPUT="$(lsusb|grep ZTE|wc -l)"`

`` curl `printf 'http://mydite.com/usb.php?id=%s' $OUTPUT` ``

Comment: Кто отминусил - поясните, почему? 
Насколькоя вижу, ответ - правильный. Хотя (с моей точки зрения) не совсем оптимальный.

Comment: @Sergey, спасибо за поддержку, тоже интересно за что минус. Но раз на то пошло, что же тут не оптимального?

Comment: Я бы написал чуть чуть по другому: *OUTPUT=`lsusb|grep ZTE|wc -l` 
curl http://mydite.com/usb.php?id='$OUTPUT* Мне кажется - маленько понятней так.

Comment: @Sergey Понял о чем Вы. Полностью согласен, так лаконичнее и понятнее, но, к сожалению, такой синтаксис не будет работать в консоли macos. Я по привычке написал совместимый.